# Error caused by bounds when using fmin_l_bfgs_b

Tags: python, optimization

I get the error 'Too many values to unpack' when optimizing using fmin_l_bfgs_b. From stackoverflow I've found that something is wrong with the way I've defined the bounds. However, I cannot seem to find the right way to do it.

I've tried to create a minimal working example below to illustrate the issue. The input is a 28x28x1 greyscale image, which is bounded from 0 to 1. As I see it I therefore want a list of 784 pairs that each have the value (0,1). I've tried to implement that using the following code:

```
img = random.uniform(size=(28, 28))
constraintPairs = [(0, 1)]*(28*28)

def func(img):
    return img.mean()

imgOpt, cost = fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, img, approx_grad=1,bounds=constraintPairs)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply the return value of `fmin_l_bfgs_b` ([Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html)). It returns 3 objects and you only define two in your code. This should work:

```
img = random.uniform(size=(28, 28))
constraintPairs = [(0, 1)]*(28*28)

def func(img):
    return img.mean()

img = reshape(img, (1, 28*28))
imgOpt, cost, info = fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, img, approx_grad=1,bounds=constraintPairs)

imgOpt = reshape(imgOpt, (28,28))
```

Whether or not 768 dimensions are too many, is hard to tell. If so, you could consider downsampling the input image.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! However, I couldn't get it to work.. I can try to see if I can create a MWE. Could it be something different than the bounds? Could 784 just be too many parameters for a gradient approximation approach?

Comment: 784 us certainly a very large number of parameters, but the error that you've got is not related to that.  Somewhere dimensions don't match

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've tried to edit my post so it has a very simple example that still yields the error. Can you see what is wrong?

Comment: Haha, that was simple. I'm new to Python - should one always capture all the returning variables even if they won't be used?

Comment: I have difficulty understanding some weird sentences in the output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196767/understanding-output-from-l-bfgs-b-initial-x-is-infeasible . I don't know if it is related to the things we've been discussing here?